# Missing window borders in Gnome 15.10

Tags: gnome, 15.10, window-manager, window, borders

Just installed Ubuntu 15.10 with Gnome 3. Using the Gnome Tweak-Tool I switched on Min/Maximise Buttons. 
Applications start maximised. When I un-maximise them, holding Alt and pulling down, there are no window borders, titlebars etc. and of course no Window buttons. 
How can I repair that?

Comment: Well, the problem kind of disappears if you switch to Wayland (installed about everything with "wayland" in the package name, then chose the corresponding session type at next login). Unfortunately, though this does bring back window borders, it brings back ugly windows borders...